# When receiving thought-speak, does one know who else it's addressed to?

Tags: animorphs

For example, Jake is using private thought-speak to talk to only Cassie and Marco, excluding Ax, Tobias and Rachel who are also present.

When Cassie "hears" the thought-speak, does she automatically know that it was also "heard" by Marco but not the others?

Comment: I am certain that there are examples of individuals thoughtspeaking simultaneously to a seen enemy and an unseen ally without tipping the enemy off, but I'm drawing a blank at the moment.  All of the examples I've looked up so far apparently involved public thoughtspeech, even though it almost never makes sense to use that mode.

Comment: @Ketura Yeah. Visser Three tends to use public thought-speech, even when it's extremely unstrategic.

Comment: Not even just him.  I blitzed #38 a moment ago and Arbat somehow dramatically answers a question Aximili makes to Estrid, while interrogating her on her illegal actions, no less.  Only (in-universe) explanation is that Ax was in public mode for some godforsaken reason.

Comment: @Ketura Which page?

Comment: End of chapter 23 to 24.

Comment: @Ketura Haha, yeah. It would have been extremely stupid for Ax to be in public mode at that stage. Poor kid. The war must have been getting to him.

Comment: Nice question! It's been a while since I've seen the books (but was just discussing them with Rand in [The Restaurant at the end of the Universe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38042854#38042854). I'm pretty sure that public thought-speak sounded different than private thought-speak did (kind of like when people speak louder, and differently, when they're addressing a room), so a small group might sound different from a one-to-one conversation, but I don't remember anything about if/how people knew who took part in a conversation.

Comment: To make sure I understand; your question is basically "if a small group are thought-speaking, will the recipients get the message as a CC or as a BCC?"?

Comment: @Shokhet yeah, that is pretty much what I meant